# PowerShell command result as Array in 1 cell

Tags: arrays, powershell

please advice, why below command puts results in 1 Array cell only ?

`$array = @((Get-Service '*Event*' | Select-Object name | format-table -hidetableheaders | Out-String).trim())`

Result looks like:

```
PS D:\dev> Write-Host $array[0]
EventLog
EventSystem
SystemEventsBroker
```

```
PS D:\dev> $Array.Count
1
```

Answer (score 1):

`Out-String` creates a single (possibly multi-line) string from the input, so your `$array` variable doesn't actually contain an array - it looks more like this:

```
$array = @'
EventLog
EventSystem
SystemEventsBroker
'@
```

If you want an array consisting of the `Name` values from each service controller object, use `Select-Object -ExpandProperty` or `ForEach-Object -MemberName`:

```
$serviceNames = Get-Service '*Event*' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
# or
$serviceNames = Get-Service '*Event*' | ForEach-Object -MemberName Name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = @(Get-Service '*Event*' | Select-Object name)
```

Try to use above command to get the expected output

please advice, why below command puts results in 1 Array cell only ? // Because you are using format command and also `out-string`. So, because of that it is into one cell